# Сохранение целой строки данных из DataGrid в БД (mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

Имеется WPF-приложение, на котором `DataGrid`, выбирающий данные из Mysql-базы.
Есть ли возможность отправить в БД вновь добавленную строку (целиком) из `DataGrid`a?
Нашел свойство `roweditending` - отлично подходит, но не пойму, как теперь данные из полей `Grid`a передать в поля БД.

p.s. Например, похожее реализовано в HeidiSQL, но только по ячейкам.
Помогите разобраться, спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, следите как форматируется ваш текст. Вы случайно поставили два служебных символа несколько не туда.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я бы сделал следущим образом:

1. Подключил бы PetaPoco для взаимодействия с БД (не обязательно, но так проще)
2. Создал лист нужных элементов(напр. Article) и подключил бы как датаСоурс в ДатаГридВью
3. на roweditending обновлял нужный элемент через PetaPoco просто методом сейв нужного элемента. :)

на вскидку этих действий должно хватить.